# highcharts export server offline?

Tags: highcharts, export

i just tried to export one of my highcharts-charts to PDF but it doesn't seem to work anymore. yesterday it worked. i did no changes to my code.

the status bar of firefox just says: `waiting for export.highcharts.com`

is anyone else experiencing this issue or this is on my network's side?

Comment: http://export.highcharts.com/ seems to be up, could you send us your chart configuration?

Comment: highcharts.com may not be down, as problem might be on your side. you can also build app using steps given on their side to deploy it offline using Java + Maven.

Comment: now seems to work again for me smoothly... maybe there was a temporary network problem on my or their side... hard to tell.